# Delete lines with lower/higher ISO date using awk and/or sed

Tags: awk, sed, pipe, ksh

I've the following file:

```
DATA;ORA;TESTO log;AMBIENTE;JOBNAME;NOMEAPP;NOMESCRIPT;PARAMETRI;
20130216;17-02-2014;15:15:13;Devi valorizzare la variabile AMBIENTE con "BCOLL" o "BPROD" ;;
20130427;17-02-2014;15:15:13;Devi valorizzare la variabile AMBIENTE con "BCOLL" o "BPROD" ;;
20131010;17-02-2014;15:15:13;Devi valorizzare la variabile AMBIENTE con "BCOLL" o "BPROD" ;;
20130217;17-02-2014;15:15:13;Devi valorizzare la variabile AMBIENTE con "BCOLL" o "BPROD" ;;
20130217;17-02-2014;15:15:13;Devi valorizzare la variabile AMBIENTE con "BCOLL" o "BPROD" ;;
20130217;17-02-2014;15:15:13;Devi valorizzare la variabile AMBIENTE con "BCOLL" o "BPROD" ;;
20140217;17-02-2014;15:15:13;Devi valorizzare la variabile AMBIENTE con "BCOLL" o "BPROD" ;;
```

The first line is the date in ISO format increasing in every line.

I want to cut all the line older than a given date using only one line of shell script with grep or awk or sed.

Be careful to the header with description fields.

It's important to be compatible with AIX, Linux, Solaris, so not sed -i.

I've this command that extract some line but also the first empy line.

```
awk -F ";" '$1 < 20140101 {print $1}' log.csv
```

piping with another `| awk '!/$1/' log.csv` it doesnt' work maybe because there's multiple lines.

it doesn't work also piping with sed:

```
sed '/$1/ d' < log.csv
```

But also this one doesn't work:

```
for i in awk -F ";" '$1 < 20140101 {print $1}' log.csv; do awk '!/$i/' log.csv; done
```

Answer (score 2):

NR==1 is true in `awk` for the first line. For the rest, just use the comparison

```
awk -F\; 'NR==1 || $1 < 20140101 { print }'
```

Comment: You posted this as I was typing my answer. The first word in the header line will be greater than any integer, so the `NR==1` isn't functionally necessary, although it has the advantage of being more explicit.

Comment: @Emmet: It will also work if the header changes to something else :)

Comment: which is only a functional advantage if the header changes to something that also means “date” but is numerical, which seems a tad unlikely :)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
awk -F';' '$1>=20140101 {print}' log.csv
```

Luckily, ISO dates compare correctly as integers.

Comment: Thanks everybody. I've found a solution like yours just few minutes ago:
`awk -F ";" '$1 > 20130217' < log.csv > log.tmp && mv log.tmp log.csv`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n "1 p;/^20140101/,$ p" log.csv
```

if you want to change the file with sed and compatible for every environement, you need to use a temporary file, still on 1 line of shell but many instruction on it

```
sed -n "1 p;/^20140101/,$ p" log.csv >/tmp/log.csv;mv /tmp/log.csv log.csv
```